# How to use @angular/cli and non angular script

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I just upgraded an application to Angular 5 and wanted to try out @angular/cli because until now I just different webpack configs derived from the angular starter package.

Our build is straight forward with one exception I'm not sure how to handle.

We use adal.js (basically an JS OAuth Library for Micosoft ADFS) and need to create a second html file with a simple Javascript (transpiled from TypesScript) which has nothing to do with Angular.
All it does is handle the GET response from ADFS and redirect to the Angular Application.

So far we just defined multiple entry points in webpack and use the HtmlWebpackPlugin to seperate the chunks like so

```
entry: {
            'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
            'main': AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts'
                : './src/main.browser.ts',
            'frameRedirect': './src/frame-redirect.ts'
        },

// under plugins
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'src/frameRedirect.html',
                filename: 'frameRedirect.html',
                chunks: ['frameRedirect'],
                inject: 'head'
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'src/index.html',
                metadata: METADATA,
                chunksSortMode: 'manual',
                chunks: ['vendor', 'polyfills', 'main']
            }),
```

Does @angular/cli provide a way to do that?
Defining a second application in `angular-cli.json` doesn't work because it's not an angular application.

Or do I have to define a second process which compiles, uglifies, minifies etc. my script?

Or stay with standard webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying it (don't even know if it even works).

What I do now

- compile the ts files (in my case frame-redirect.ts) to javascript with webpack/rollup or whatever you want to use.
- include it as assets in `.angular-cli.json`

  ```
  { "glob": "frame-redirect.js", "input": "../node_modules/a-private-package/dist/libs/", "output": "./" }
  ```

I decided it's easer and faster to completly rely on angular-cli for my app and have a second/unrelated building process (which has to run before you compile your angular app).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem when you want to upgrade from regular angular app to an angular/@cli project is that you need an .angular-cli.json file, which is generated when you create the project : ng new projectName

I succeed to did it, by creating an angular project in another directory, then I just moved my src/app directory. That's the easiest I could recommand.

Let me know if you face difficulties ;)

Comment: upgrading is not my issue. My issue is generating a second non angular script and *.html file along my angular application

Comment: If you are using angular cli, and if you can edit your json file, can't you just copy paste your scripts in the scripts array ?

Comment: no, because it's not part of the angular app itself